# Shifting from SurfaceView to GLSurfaceView?

Tags: android, surfaceview, glsurfaceview

I'm currently developing a game, which only uses 2D graphics.

In the game i extensively use android's `SurfaceView` to display my graphics.
I've heard that `GLSurfaceView` uses Hardware-accelerated graphics, and i can increase performance of my app using that instead of the current `SurfaceView`.

Currently, i have a class extending `SurfaceView`, which updates and renders the game state, when methods `update()` and `render()` are called by my own thread class extending `Thread`. The Thread basically helps me maintain a nearly constant FPS.

NOW THE PROBLEM:
How do i change from `SurfaceView` to `GLSurfaceView`, and call methods to update and render game state from the Thread, to still have control over the FPS. I read the android documentation on OpenGL ES, and i can't quite understand how to use the `GLSurfaceView.Renderer`.

If someone can explain how can i easily switch from `SurfaceView` to `GLSurfaceView`, It'd be of great help! Thanks!

Comment: I simply need to know what methods of the GLSurfaveView.Renderer or any other class, should i update the game state in, and what method should i use to render the state. I have lots of could that i could copy-paste(and probably tweek a bit) so i dont wanna be starting all over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Class that displays your game will extend `GLSurfaceView`.  Your rendering class will implement `Renderer`.  In your `Renderer` class you will need to add these unimplemented methods:  `onDrawFrame()`, `onSurfaceChanged()`, `and onSurfaceCreated()`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i found that much out from the android documentation. Sorry for not mentioning it in my answer. So you are saying that i keep my 'update()' code in the class which extends GLSurfaceView, and move my 'render()' code to another class extending Renderer and put it in the onDrawFrame() method. Please clarify. and will i be able to control the execution of that method from my thread?

Comment: The game is updated in the onDrawFrame() method.  Your GLSurfaceView is basically an empty window.  The renderer handles all of the game logic.